# Why is std::unique() broken for a an equality relationship that changes between elements?

Tags: c++, function, lambda, unique

I wrote some code to iterate over a vector. It allows up to two occurrences of each element before considering subsequent occurrences as duplicates.

```
int main() {

    std::vector<int> vec =  {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end()); 
    auto last = std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end(),[count = 1](const auto& a, const auto& b) mutable
    {
        if(a != b)
        {   
            count = 1;
            return false ; 
        }else{
            return ++count > 2; 
        
        }
    });
    vec.erase(last, vec.end()); 
    
    for(auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it){std::cout << *it << '\n'; }
   return 0; 
}
```

When I run the code, the result is as follows:

```
1
1
1
2
3
3
4
5
5
```

which is not the desired result.

So my question is, how is this problem generated regarding the first element of the vector?

I worked on the lambda body a little bit. However, it just made more complex problems.

Comment: Do you know the implementation details of `std::unique` to guarantee that the approach you're taking will work?  [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).  See the **Possible implementations** section.  BTW, I ran your code using Visual Studio, and got `1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5`, so that indicates that different compilers will implement `std::unique` differently.

Comment: [Here is a possible solution](https://godbolt.org/z/e913K3Koa).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I liked that idea and made a version [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/GW3TaY5Ph) as an option but I'm not sure if `std::erase_if`s _Predicate_ needs to be equally preserving (like the `std::predicate` concept requires), which it isn't in my version, so I removed it for now. Need to read up on the named requirement _Predicate_ tomorrow. If that solution is ok, I'll add it then.

Answer (score 9):

[`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) @ cppreference.com:

> Elements are compared using the given binary predicate `p`. The behavior is undefined if it is not an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

Since your [BinaryPredicate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BinaryPredicate) changes whether two elements are to be considered equal during the course of the running algorithm, it does not fulfill the equivalence relation requirement - and your program therefore has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

---

Here are two of the many possible solutions to your problem.

A C++23 solution could look like this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    auto max2view = vec
                  | std::views::chunk_by(std::equal_to{})
                  | std::views::transform([](auto&& rng) {
                        return std::views::take(rng, 2);
                    })
                  | std::views::join;

    // vec is unaffected by the above - use max2view to iterate:
    for (int x : max2view) {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
}
```

- `vec | std::views::chunk_by(std::equal_to{})` - Create a view of subranges where all elements are equal.
- `std::views::transform(auto&& rng)` - Transform each subrange by taking max 2 elements from each.
- `std::views::join` - Join all the views of subranges into one view.

---

Another solution could be to create a `std::map` of `value`/`counter`, then `clear()` the vector and then re-fill it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};
    std::map<int, unsigned> counters;

    for(int x : vec) ++counters[x]; // count the occurances of `x`

    vec.clear();
    
    for(auto[x, count] : counters) { // refill vec with at most 2 of each:
        vec.insert(vec.end(), std::min(count, 2), x);
    }

    for (int x : vec) {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
}
```